# Laravel AJAX, append values dynamically

Tags: ajax, laravel

I tried to append several values in the same column of Laravel AJAX datatable. Here is what I typed in the controller :

```js
$table->addColumn('academic_options', function ($row) {
                return ($row->academic_section ? $row->academic_section->code : '') . ', ' . ($row->option_1 ? $row->option_1->code : '') .
                ', ' . ($row->option_2 ? $row->option_2->code : '') . ', ' . ($row->option_3 ? $row->option_3->code : '') . ', ' . ($row->option_9 ? $row->option_9->code : '');
            });
```

And this is what is shown  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l17H5.png)

How should I do it so the values will be separated properly, if possible how can i create a list of existed values, the empty value would be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Collect the right array in the right order, and then do "implode"

```php
$array = [1,2,3,4,5];

echo implode(', ', $array); // Output: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```